# Issue in the Cell reuse concept

Tags: ios

I am using a Table view and in which I am having a custom cell with a check box in it. As soon as the tableview the checkbox in the cell is already selected by the calculation of some logic. There is a bar button on the top of the screen . What i want is that on the click of that button the quantity associated with the selected checkbox should fall into an array.

For example if I am having six cells currently in the tableview all of which are selected but only four are currently visible. Due to this on the click of the button only 4 values are added in the array.

How can I detect all the checkboxes selected at the time of click of the button?
The code on the click of the button is:
        - (IBAction)btn_AddRefill_click:(id)sender{

```
for (int i=0; i < [arr_RxDetails count]; i++) {


    NSIndexPath * indexpath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    //NSLog(@"The indexpath is %@",indexpath);
   MyMedicationCell * cell = (MyMedicationCell *) [tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexpath];

    // here I am checking if the button is selected or not.
    if ([cell.btn_RxCheck isSelected]) {
        //NSLog(@"the Rx id is %@",[[arr_RxDetails objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"RxId"]);
        [self.arr_RxNo addObject:[[arr_RxDetails objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"RxId"]];


    }
}
NSLog(@"the array is %@",arr_RxNo);
[self.obj_AddRxs didSelectRxs:self.arr_RxNo];
```

}

As in this code the loop runs for 6 times but it detects the check box to be selected only in the 4 cells as they are currently visible right now. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I think you should store the whether the values are checked on not in an array the size of your entire data set.  In this case 6.

Add a target method to the `valueChanged` `UIControlEvent` for the checkbox.  In this method store the value of whether the row or not is checked.

Additionally in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`: set the value of the checkbox based on the contents of the array.

If you try and use the actual cell as a basis for storing the data you'd need to keep the whole of the table in memory, which defeats the object of the efficiency gained by data and UI virtualisation that UITableView offers.

Hope that helps,

Dave

Comment: but how can I detect whether the checkbox is checked or not at the time of loading of the view. Since the check box is a part of the cell. It's all properties are managed by the cell itself.Suggest something o this. As the value changed method is not running at the time of view loading so I am no able to do detect the checkbox as it is managed by the tableview which is still showing 4 selected.

Comment: In your cellForRowAtIndexPath: when you create the cell you can add a target to a the checkbox control which is a method in your UITableViewController.  In this method you would store the value of whether the checkbox is checked or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `NSMutableArray` `selectedCheckbox` which will keep track of selected checkboxes.

Whenever a check box is selected just add checkbox number to array

```
[selectedCheckbox addObject:@"2"];
```

and whenever it is unchecked just remove it from array

```
[selectedCheckbox removeObject:@"2"];
```

Now you can refer to this array to get the count of selected checkboxes as well as index of selected checkboxes.
**Hope this will help you.**